# react-query with graphql-request: Error boundary not running

Tags: reactjs, graphql, graphql-js, react-query, react-error-boundary

I have the following code:

```
const queryClient = new QueryClient({
    defaultOptions: {
        useErrorBoundary: true,
        queries: {
            suspense: true,
            useErrorBoundary: true,
            retry: 0,
        }
    }
});


const useUsers = () => {
    return useQuery("users", async () => {
        const users = await fetchUsers();
        console.log(users);
        return users;
    })
};

function UserList() {
    const { data, isFetching, error, status } = useUsers();
    const { users } = data;

   // return some render with users
}
```

My fetchUsers method:

```
export function fetchUsers(fields = ['id', 'name']) {
    console.info("fetch users");
    return request(`${process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_URL}/graphql`, gql`
        query getUsers {
  users {
    ${fields},nice
  }
}`);
}
```

My App.js:

```
<QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
            <ErrorBoundary
                fallbackRender={({ error }) => (
                    <div>
                        There was an error!{" "}
                        <pre style={{ whiteSpace: "normal" }}>{error.message}</pre>
                    </div>
                )}
                onReset={() => {
                    // reset the state of your app so the error doesn't happen again
                }}
            >
                <UserList/>
            </ErrorBoundary>
        </QueryClientProvider>
```

I expect to see the ErrorBoundary running when I type unexisting graphql field (aka `nice`) - but my react app crashes with:

[image]

```
Error: Cannot query field "nice" on type "User". Did you mean "name"?
```

Why the error boundary don't catch this error? Any idea what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Have you set `useErrorBoundary: true` to turn on that option, because I’m not seeing that on your code

Comment: I think I missed it, where it should be set?

Comment: As an option to useQuery (third parameter is an options object), or globally on the QueryClient

Comment: I set it now, same issue